# Drawing multiple Google Charts on a single page?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Basically my JavaScript receives data like this: `year = {month1, ...., month12}`. Each month stores data for 3 graphs. `month1 = {graph1_data,..., graph3_data}`

I wish to draw charts for all of them using Google Charts. So that makes it 12 * 3 = 36 charts. I have written the following code logic. But it fails to work.

```
for ( month in year )
{
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
           // draw graph1
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            // code
            // code
            // data.addColumn()
            // data.addColumn()
            data.addRows(data_table);
            var options = {title: month, height:100};
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
    document.querySelector('#'+month+' .graph1'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
    });

    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
           // draw graph2
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            // code
            // code
            // data.addColumn()
            // data.addColumn()
            data.addRows(data_table);
            var options = {title: month, height:100};
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
    document.querySelector('#'+month+' .graph2'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
    });

    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
           // draw graph3
           google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            // code
            // code
            // data.addColumn()
            // data.addColumn()
            data.addRows(data_table);
            var options = {title: month, height:100};
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
    document.querySelector('#'+month+' .graph3));
            chart.draw(data, options);
    });
}
```

It draws 3 charts for `month12`. Now why does this happen? Does this mean I must call `setOnLoadCallback` 36 times? Isn't there any alternative way?

**Edit**
It looks like once Google Chart API is loaded, the callbacks in all the  `setOnLoadCallback`s is called once. Which probably explains why I get only one graph, since at the time of execution of the function, the loop would have stopped at `month12`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out what is going wrong here.

You are only *registering* a callback with the Google Charts API, not actually *calling* it in your `for(month in year)` loop. The callback is called (as you can guess) when relevant resources have finished loading and the Charts API can start drawing. Unfortunately your globally defined var `month` is now equal to `month12`. This is the state after your for loop completes:

```
month = year.month12;
callback_for_graph_1 = <anonymous function 1>
callback_for_graph_2 = <anonymous function 2>
callback_for_graph_3 = <anonymous function 3>
```

As you can imagine, now when the callbacks, they are each called only once, with `month = year.month12`. Hence the three graphs, all with `month12` data.

So how do you fix this? Here's how:

1. Initialise three callbacks only **once**. No need to keep them anonymous.

   ```
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(callbackForGraph1);
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(callbackForGraph2);
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(callbackForGraph3);

   function callbackForGraph1 {
   // do your thing
   }
   function callbackForGraph2 {
   // do your thing
   }
   function callbackForGraph3 {
   // do your thing
   }
   ```
2. Iterate over all the months inside each callback, and create a new `Chart` instance for each month. Also draw it.

   ```
   function callbackForGraph1() {
     for(month in year) {
       // draw graph1
       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
       // code
       // code
       // data.addColumn()
       // data.addColumn()
       data.addRows(data_table);
       var options = {title: month, height:100};
       // this is your Chart instance ->
       var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.querySelector('#'+month+' .graph1'));
       // draw it!
       chart.draw(data, options);
     }
   }
   ```
3. *Profit?*

You might also want to store each `Chart` instance in a array or dictionary style object. That way you can later make changes to your plots, instead of having to regenerate and replace them.

---

**OLD ANSWER:** This happens because you draw the chart for `graph_1` in the same HTML element for each month. So the chart for `graph_1[month2]` overwrites the chart for `graph_1[month1]`. Since `graph_1[month12]` is the last data to be processed, you get the chart for `month12`. Likewise occurs for `graph_2` and `graph_3`.

What you can try is appending a new `svg` or `vml` element to your HTML `document` every time the plotting callback is called. This can be done from within the callback itself. That way you get a new chart for every month for every graph.

Comment: No. I make sure I write to 36 different HTML locations.

Comment: Then you should be getting 36 different plots. Maybe you should expand on your code a little bit. What have you written inside those callback functions?

Comment: You are correct! Careless mistake on my part. I also put all the three `drawChart` functions in one callback. :D